# Search not working in IE. Only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, search

I'm having this issue with the search field. When I Hit enter button, the search is trigered, but only works sucessfuly in Chrome. If I hit the enter button in IE, the only change in page, if i hit the button, to make the search for a second time... works.

```
$( document ).ready(function(event) {
        $("#searchField").keypress(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                search_value = $('#searchField').val();
                proj_id = $('#projectId').val();
                //alert (search_value + '-' + proj_id);
                searchMeeting(search_value, proj_id);
            }

        });
    });

function searchMeeting(search_value, proj_id) {

    var lastSearchValue = $('#searchField').val();
    if (proj_id != "") {
        $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
        $.ajax({
            url : '../meeting/searchMeeting.action',
            type : 'post', // method
            dataType : 'html',
            data : { // data to send
                "searchValue" : search_value,
                "projectId" : proj_id
            },
            error : function() { // fail
                alert('Failed to search!');
            },
            success : function(html) {// success
                $('#backToList').attr("style","display: none;");
                $("#meeting_content").html(html);
                $("#searchField").val(lastSearchValue);
                bindTableEvents();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a input type "search" ?

Comment: Which IE? They dont all support search very well

Comment: Also, is the ajaxcall triggered?

Comment: I'm using IE 8 (simulating).

Comment: I'm using input type text. If use type search doesn't work too

Comment: In fact, the search works only SOMETIMES.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for the keycode, you could place it one the submit of the form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="search" id="searchField" />
</form>

$("#searchField").closest('form').on('submit',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    search_value = $('#searchField').val();
    proj_id = $('#projectId').val();
    //alert (search_value + '-' + proj_id);
    searchMeeting(search_value, proj_id);  
});
```

Offcourse you can add an id to the form and bind the event to that

Comment: I believe that issue in the function searchMeeting.